# iframe Vimeo fullscreen button not showing

Tags: video, iframe, embed, fullscreen, vimeo

For some reason, the Vimeo iframe is missing the fullscreen button. It works if I use the official embed code directly in the HTML, but not this way.

**JS:**

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var videoid = document.querySelector(".active .video-id");
videoid.setAttribute("src", "allow='autoplay; fullscreen' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen"); 
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + videoid.id + "?autoplay=1&portrait=0&title=0 width='100' height='100' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; fullscreen' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen"); 
videoid.appendChild(iframe);
```

**CSS:**

```
    .video-id {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: -1;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .video-id iframe,  
    .video-id object,  
    .video-id embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this in an old question but I came across a similar issue today and I think I have your answer.

It looks like you're setting all of the iframe's settings in the "src" attribute.  "src" should only contain the link to video.

Currently you have:

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + videoid.id + "?autoplay=1&portrait=0&title=0 width='100' height='100' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; fullscreen' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen");
```

Which should be expanded into these lines:

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + videoid.id + "?autoplay=1&portrait=0&title=0");
iframe.setAttribute("width","100");
iframe.setAttribute("height","100");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder","0");
iframe.setAttribute("allow","autoplay; fullscreen");
iframe.setAttribute("webkitallowfullscreen","");
iframe.setAttribute("mozallowfullscreen","");
iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen","");
```

As those settings are all separate attributes and not part of the source.

Comment: `iframe.setAttribute("allow","autoplay; fullscreen");` should be `iframe.setAttribute("allow","autoplay");`.